# How do I make an MX record to point to a Google Workspace email address of the same domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-dns, gcloud-compute

I purchased [anarchitecture.io](https://anarchitecture.io) from *Google Domains*, and pointed it to a *Google Cloud Compute* instance Apache server by adding an A record with the IP address of the server.

I also set that domain to "Use custom name servers" and set them to the following addresses.

```
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com
```

I created the email address anarchitect@anarchitecture.io with Google Workspaces. It is not receiving mail. I assume that I have to set up an MX record to point to the correct mail servers for this service. How do I set up an MX record without breaking my website? What addresses should I point to with the MX record?

Comment: Would [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6248174?hl=en) help?

Comment: @jabbson , thanks for the suggestion, but it won't let me set a "synthetic record" because I have already set a "custom name server." I think I have to set it in Google Cloud DNS not Google Domains since the DNS is redirected to that.

Comment: Here is [another doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9222085?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-add-the-new-mx-records) I found, this one talks about setting dns mx record in Cloud DNS

Comment: @jabbson , that's what I needed! I guess I didn't understand that you have to add the priority number in the entry as well.

Answer (score 1):

- In order for your Google Wotrkspace account to recivied emails please follow the steps described in [Google Workspace MX setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I had to enter the following addresses to the MX record in *Cloud DNS*, including the priority number.

```
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```